# Android service restarts again and again in background

Tags: android, android-service

Few days ago I had a terrible problem with my app. My app was restarting a specific work again and again in background. After sometime I have found that all the problem comes from my service's `onStartCommand()` method. For example I start a download task by start the service with give it the information like URL, name, path etc. and it all works fine. After sometime when I am on any other app. I gets a toast that the same download task is restarted. So, clearly all the problem with in the service. I searched on the service little bit, but confuse why the service restarts. If anyone give the right information it will be very helpful. Here is the service code :

```
 public class DownloadService extends Service {

    private DownloadManager mDownloadManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mDownloadManager = new DownloadManager(this, (FatherApplication) getApplication());
     }


    protected boolean addDownload(String fileU, String fileP, String fileN){
        try{
            if(mDownloadManager != null){
                mDownloadManager.addTask(fileU, fileP, fileN);
            }
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        FatherApplication mApp =(FatherApplication) getApplication();
        /** I am not sure the Global has been intilized or not, So i need to check is the global data is intilized or 
         * has been null. if null intilized it by calling GlobalData.getIntense(). */
         if(mApp.getGlobalData() == null){
             mApp.setGlobalData();
         }

        if (mDownloadManager == null) {
            mDownloadManager = new DownloadManager(this, (FatherApplication) getApplication());         
            }   
        String action = intent.getAction();
        int type = -1;

        if(action.equals( SystemIntent.INTENT_ACTION_START_SARVICE )){
            type= intent.getIntExtra(SystemIntent.TYPE, -1);   
            }

        /* --- Add --- */
        if(type != -1 && type == SystemIntent.Types.ADD){
            String fname= intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_NAME);
            String fpath= intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_PATH);
            String furl = intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_URL);
            this.addDownload(furl,fpath,fname);
            }

        /* --- paused --- */
        if(type != -1 && type == SystemIntent.Types.PAUSE){
         String fname= intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_NAME);
         String fpath= intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_PATH);
         String furl = intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_URL);
         if(this.mDownloadManager.isThatARunningTask(furl,fname,fpath))
         this.mDownloadManager.pauseTask(furl,fname,fpath);
         else Toast.makeText(this,"That's not running task.",2).show();
       }
        /* --- deleted --- */
        if(type != -1 && type == SystemIntent.Types.DELETE){
            String fname= intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_NAME);
            String fpath= intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_PATH);
            String furl = intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_URL);
            this.mDownloadManager.deleteTask(furl,fname,fpath);
        }

        /* --- source deleted --- */
        if(type != -1 && type == SystemIntent.Types.DELETE_SOURCE){
            String fname= intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_NAME);
            String fpath= intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_PATH);
            String furl = intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_URL);
            this.mDownloadManager.deleteTask(furl,fname,fpath);
        }

        /* --- restarted --- */
        if(type != -1 && type == SystemIntent.Types.RESTART){
            String fname= intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_NAME);
            String fpath= intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_PATH);
            String furl = intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_URL);
            this.mDownloadManager.restartTask(furl,fname,fpath);
        }

        /* --- resumed --- */
        if(type != -1 && type == SystemIntent.Types.RESUME){
            String fname= intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_NAME);
            String fpath= intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_PATH);
            String furl = intent.getStringExtra(SystemIntent.FILE_URL);
            if(!this.mDownloadManager.isThatARunningTask(furl,fname,fpath))
                this.mDownloadManager.resumeTask(furl,fname,fpath);
                else Toast.makeText(this,"That's a running task.",2).show();
            }
        return this.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    /** I going to destroy the service , shibo you should do your importent works. */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){ 
    this.mDownloadManager.close();
    super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start an intent

```
//to register the services
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(ServicesTemplate.MY_ACTION);
registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
//to start this services
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Mainactivity.this, Yourserviceclassname.class);
startService(myIntent);
```

To stop the intent

```
Intent oIntent = new Intent(Mainactivity.this, Yourserviceclassname.class);
stopService(oIntent);
```

you have to stop the services after download complete

Answer (score 0):

When you start any service, you need to stop it too, once the purpose is served. You can stop the service in two ways.

1.You can stop a service via the `stopService()` method. No matter how frequently you called the startService(intent) method, one call to the stopService() method stops the service.

2.A service can terminate itself by calling the `stopSelf()` method. This is typically done if the service finishes his work.

In your case, I would suggest you to use `Intentservice` instead of Service as the `IntentServices` for one time tasks like downloading a file.

```
// Start the  service
public void startService(View view) {
    startService(new Intent(this.your_activity, Your_Service.class));
}

// Stop the  service

public void stopService(View view) {

    stopService(new Intent(this.your_activity, Your_Service.class));
}
```

For more information on services you can refer,

1. [Tutorial on Services By Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) 2. [Android service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)